# C - 3rd scanf modifies a variable from 2nd scanf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I think I've tried anything (flushing stdin, scanf to consume newline etc.), but nothing works as I had hoped. For some reason a 3rd scanf modifies a variable from 2nd scanf in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char first_name[16], last_name[21];
  char filename[11];
  FILE *opening;

  printf("The program saves your first and last name into a file.\n");

  printf("Enter your first name:");
  scanf("%s", first_name);
  getchar();

  printf("Enter your last name:");
  scanf(" %s", last_name);
  getchar();

  printf("File where you want to save your name:");
  scanf(" %s", filename);

  opening = fopen(filename, "wb");

  fprintf(opening, "%s %s", first_name, last_name);
  printf("\nSuccessfully saved the data!");

  fclose(opening);

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
The program saves your first and last name into a file.
Enter your first name: John
Enter your last name: Doe
File where you want to save your name: filename.txt

Successfully saved the data!
```

All fine and dandy except that the contents of filename.txt is this:

> John t

I'm guessing that the 't' character comes from 'txt' somehow, but I've just started learning C and I don't know how to fix this piece of code to work. Could you gurus help me please?

Comment: @Bathsheba no, I provided a shorter filename. With `filename.txt` it segfaulted.

Comment: I would also not be able to use your program. Christellasonesius Winser-Warburton-Saxe-Coburg-Gotha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filename` buffer is too small.

You write `filename.txt`, which is 12 characters, plus the zero to finish it, makes 13. You only allocate 11. Try like this:

```
char filename[20];
```

and it should work.

Be careful though with using `scanf`, it can lead to very nasty problems, as you are encountering right now. It is good in experimenting and learning C, as it shows you how important correct memory handling is. For any real project you should consider using different functions or frameworks.

Comment: actually 14 characters are needed due to the space before `%s`. Nasty problems indeed.

Comment: Wow, it really was easy as correcting the filename buffer! Now it worked. Actually I should do this so that the filename complies with 8.3 filename rule, and now I think I can continue on..

Comment: The 8.3 filename rule? Does that still exist?

Comment: @Bathsheba: In my case it seems 13 characters was enough for filename.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: It does in this assignment :D

Comment: @nyyp; that's the beauty of undefined behaviour. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Note that it's 1 space + filename as OP has " %s"

Comment: @BartFriederichs: I have a lot of ways to go in terms of memory handling, I come from Python background where pretty much everything works behind the scenes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering filename.txt as your file name, then you are overrunning your buffer for `filename`. That is *undefined behaviour* and is the cause of the strange results.

To fix, make `char filename[11];` larger, remembering to allow 1 extra character for the NULL terminator. In your very specific case, that would be `char filename[14];` allowing for the errant space before `%s` in your `scanf` call.

Otherwise, all looks fine.

Comment: Your other memory buffers are also a little stingy. E.g. the first name. Regards, Christellasonesius.

Comment: Ah, now that I fixed filename[11] -> filename[12] I only get 'John' to filename.txt.

Comment: @nyyp: and the space for the NULL terminator plus the prefixed space? That makes it 14. On windows, make your life easier. Allow 1 + MAX_PATH + 1

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf()` on strings is dangerous, as **it may read in more data into the buffer than the buffer provides memory**.

If scanning in strings one shall always tell `scanf()` how much characters to read by adding this number to the format passed to `scanf()`:

```
char file_name[11];

...

scanf("%10s", file_name); /* As file_name provides memor for 11 characters, read a
                             maximum of 10 characters into file_name leaving 1 
                             character room for the necessary `0-`terminator indicating 
                             the end of the "string". */
```

---

Also your code misses error checking on the `fopen` system call.

Better do something like this:

```
opening = fopen(filename, "wb");
if (NULL == opening)
{
  perror("fopen() failed");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```